# Offset() property misbehaves in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

In IE8, I am trying to get the left offset values of a div elements whose style is set as "align=center"

```
<div id="container" align="center"></div>

 <script>
     alert($("#container").offset().left);
 </script>
```

This div is placed at the center of the page, but it displays the value as 0 in IE 8 browser (I am using windows 8). But working fine in higher versions of IE.

So please let me know how to get the exact offset value.

Thanks !

Comment: which jquery version are you using?

Comment: I am using jQuery version 1.10.2

Comment: 1.10 is not compatible with IE8